# Logging content in separate files for different batch jobs in Java

Tags: java, slf4j

I have several projects written in Java Spring framework. I trigger a batch job from a project and all the batch logs (logs present in multiple classses) are written to a single file using slf4j logger.

I want to write the log content in a separate file for each batch job.

I tried to find a way to do this using slf4j logger, however I could not do so. Is there any other library I can use for this purpose?

Comment: What is your logging implementation? How are you invoking the batch job?

Comment: Presently, the logging is done in tomcat cataliana.out file using slf4j logger library. The batch jobs are simply execution of java threads.

Comment: If I understood you, you have many WARs deployed in Tomcat and each WAR represents a Batch. Is that correct?